# Pandas merge two dataframes with the same structure

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assume I have two dataframes:

```
    x1  x2  x3  
y1  a1  a1  a1      
y2  b1  b1  b1     
y3  c1  c1  c1  

    x1  x2  x3  
y1  a2  a2  a2      
y2  b2  b2  b2     
y3  c2  c2  c2
```

Which is the easiest way to get the following dataframe with each element a list of the two values from the same place in original dataframes?

```
    x1        x2       x3  
y1  [a1,a2]  [a1,a2]  [a1,a2]     
y2  [b1,b2]  [b1,b2]  [b1,b2]     
y3  [c1,c2]  [c1,c2]  [c1,c2]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `applymap`

```
In [953]: df1.applymap(lambda x: [x]) + df2.applymap(lambda x: [x])
Out[953]:
          x1        x2        x3
y1  [a1, a2]  [a1, a2]  [a1, a2]
y2  [b1, b2]  [b1, b2]  [b1, b2]
y3  [c1, c2]  [c1, c2]  [c1, c2]
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems more flexible and can be applied to `reduce`.

Answer (score 4):

One (out of many) possible solution:

```
In [63]: d1.astype(str).add(',').add(d2.astype(str)).apply(lambda x: x.str.split(','))
Out[63]:
          x1        x2        x3
y1  [a1, a2]  [a1, a2]  [a1, a2]
y2  [b1, b2]  [b1, b2]  [b1, b2]
y3  [c1, c2]  [c1, c2]  [c1, c2]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could it deal with `int` or `float` types?

Comment: @natsuapo, i've updated my answer - it'll produce lists of strings